# Fatal error: exception Match_failure("main.ml", 8, 15)

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, non-exhaustive-patterns

Here is my code:

```
type 'a tree = Empty | N of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree


let absolute x = 
    if x > 0 then x 
    else -x

let rec node = function 
    | N(_, Empty, Empty) -> 1
    | N(_, g, d) -> 1 + node g + node d

let rec balanced = function 
    | N(_, Empty, Empty) -> 0
    | N(_,g,d) when absolute (node g - node d) > 1 -> 1
    | N(_,g,d) when absolute (node g - node d) <= 1 -> balanced g + balanced d


let () = print_int (balanced (N ('x', N ('x', Empty, Empty),
  N ('x', N ('x', Empty, Empty), Empty))))
```

Then it's telling me:

```
Fatal error: exception Match_failure("main.ml", 8, 15)
```

I don't understand what does it mean and it doesn't seem to indicate where my mistake comes from.

Moreover I get the following warnings:

```
File "main.ml", line 8, characters 15-93:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
Empty
File "main.ml", line 12, characters 19-190:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(N (_, Empty, N (_, _, _))|N (_, N (_, _, _), _)|Empty)
(However, some guarded clause may match this value.)
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

I mean according to me it doesn't mean anything to say that I am missing the case `N(_,_,_)`, but this case is always handled, so why is the compiler telling me that this case is not matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before taking a look at your runtime errors, it's better to look at your compiler output first (that is the warnings).

You have two warnings. The first one:

```
File "main.ml", line 8, characters 15-93:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
Empty
```

Here it tells us that your pattern matching in the `node` function does not handle the `Empty` case. Just add a `| Empty -> 0` to your pattern matching and you should be good (by the way, you won't need the incomplete `Node (_,Empty,Empty)` case anymore).

Now your second warning is a bit more tricky:

```
File "main.ml", line 12, characters 19-190:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
(N (_, Empty, N (_, _, _))|N (_, N (_, _, _), _)|Empty)
(However, some guarded clause may match this value.)
```

Here, it tells that several patterns are not matched, but that some values are guarded. And indeed the case `N (_,_,_)` is.

You can show the compiler that all `N (_,_,_)` are handled by removing the second `when` clause (that is, `when absolute (node g - node d) <= 1`). The pattern matching won't reach this point unless this clause is true so you can be sure it is. Also, you make sure you don't repeat the same computation twice this way. Note that in this pattern matching too, you did not handle the `Empty` case again. Do that.

Now let's take a look at your exception. It basically says "The pattern-matching at line 8 character 15 failed". That's your `node` function. Where you were warned that your pattern matching was incomplete. The lesson here is "don't ignore warnings, they're not bothersome, they're important".

Answer (score 1):

The warning isn't wrong. You are missing a case, and the compiler has generated an example of that case for you. That case is appearing during runtime, and as a result you're getting a match that is failing because you don't handle it.

Comment: More precisely, the compiler doesn't look at `when ...` parts ("guards") when checking for exhaustiveness. If you remove the second guard, the warning should go away.

Comment: He's also missing a case in his other match.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained the warnings and what they mean. Follow that.

I just want to add something about where your code fails currently. In the balanced function you catch the case that both left and right children are Empty and handle the case where both children are not Empty correctly. But what if only one child is Empty? In that case you compute `node g` and `node d`. One of them is Empty which is the case you didn't cover in the node function. Your example does have Nodes where only one side is Empty and there it fails.